# Create SQL function to determine if a value matches another

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-function

I realize this is somewhat of a silly example, since why would you use a function when you could just compare the value explicitly in a where clause?  So perhaps SQL is forcing silliness of the function definition to match the silliness of my desired behavior.

In any case, I'd like to write something simple like this:

```
return (@inputValue = expectedValue)
```

However, SQL doesn't appear to like that.

This works:

```
If @inputValue = expectedValue
    return 0
Else
    return 1
return -1
```

But seems clunky, especially with the final unnecessary (but necessary from SQL's perspective) return statement.

Is there a prettier way to achieve this?  Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about using a [`CASE` expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx), like this:

```
RETURN CASE WHEN @inputValue = expectedValue THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
```

Or like this:

```
RETURN CASE @inputValue WHEN expectedValue THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
```